# Conversion to TFLite model from frozen inference graph (.pb) failing?

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, roboflow

I'm working to convert a frozen inference graph I obtained from running [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wTMIrJhYsQdq_u7ROOkf0Lu_fsX5Mu8a) to a TFLite model.

I modified code I found from TensorFlow's [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert) to do so, and ran it in Google Colab:

```
import tensorflow as tf

path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/real_frozen_inference_graph.pb"

input = ["image_tensor"]
output = ["detection_boxes", "detection_scores", "detection_multiclass_scores", "detection_classes", "num_detections", "raw_detection_boxes", "raw_detection_scores"]

# Convert the model
converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(path, input_arrays=input, output_arrays=output)
print("starting conversion")

tflite_model = converter.convert()

print("done converting")

# Save the model.
with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

The runtime disconnects almost immediately after I run the cell, which is especially odd since I pay for colab pro...

I changed the code above to run on my local dev environment, but still no luck. I get a long string of raw binary code and weird-looking things like this printed to my stdout but no file is written by the termination of the script:

```
  %220 = "tfl.add"(%219, %cst_12) {fused_activation_function = "NONE"} : (tensor<?x100xf32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<?x100xf32>
  %221 = "tf.TensorArraySizeV3"(%handle_170, %210#5) {_class = ["loc:@Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/TensorArray_12"], device = ""} : (tensor<2x!tf.resource<tensor<*xf32>>>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<i32>
  %222 = "tfl.range"(%cst_10, %221, %cst_13) : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<?xi32>
  %223 = "tf.TensorArrayGatherV3"(%handle_170, %222, %210#5) {_class = ["loc:@Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/TensorArray_12"], device = "", element_shape = #tf.shape<100x2>} : (tensor<2x!tf.resource<tensor<*xf32>>>, tensor<?xi32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<?x100x2xf32>
  %224 = "tf.TensorArraySizeV3"(%handle_172, %210#6) {_class = ["loc:@Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/TensorArray_13"], device = ""} : (tensor<2x!tf.resource<tensor<*xi32>>>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<i32>
  %225 = "tfl.range"(%cst_10, %224, %cst_13) : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<?xi32>
  %226 = "tf.TensorArrayGatherV3"(%handle_172, %225, %210#6) {_class = ["loc:@Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/TensorArray_13"], device = "", element_shape = #tf.shape<>} : (tensor<2x!tf.resource<tensor<*xi32>>>, tensor<?xi32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<?xi32>
  %227 = "tfl.cast"(%226) : (tensor<?xi32>) -> tensor<?xf32>
  "std.return"(%213, %216, %223, %220, %227, %181, %186) : (tensor<?x100x4xf32>, tensor<?x100xf32>, tensor<?x100x2xf32>, tensor<?x100xf32>, tensor<?xf32>, tensor<?x?x4xf32>, tensor<?x?x2xf32>) -> ()
}) {sym_name = "main", tf.entry_function = {control_outputs = "", inputs = "image_tensor", outputs = "detection_boxes,detection_scores,detection_multiclass_scores,detection_classes,num_detections,raw_detection_boxes,raw_detection_scores"}, type = (tensor<?x?x?x3x!tf.quint8>) -> (tensor<?x100x4xf32>, tensor<?x100xf32>, tensor<?x100x2xf32>, tensor<?x100xf32>, tensor<?xf32>, tensor<?x?x4xf32>, tensor<?x?x2xf32>)} : () -> ()
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what's going wrong here? Is it printing the TFLite file to my stdout? Maybe there's something obvious I'm overlooking? I'm new to TensorFlow so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have kept `tensorflow2.0` but the colab notebook uses `TensorFlow1`. `Tensorflow2.3.X` and above only supports `tflite` conversion and is only currently available in `tfnightly-2.4.0` builds. This question is very misleading. Please update your question with the correct tensorflow versions

Comment: @papaya tflite conversion supported from 1.x

Comment: @papaya What are you being misled by? Are you aware that Tensorflow 2.0 is backward compatible with 1.x models?

Answer (score 1):

This is output of convertor where conversion fail place indicated. This is native app and python wrapper just translate this output.
This can be caused by various reasons: unimplemented ops, unimplemented inputs/outputs of ops, etc. Here how I would start:

1. Pick latest TF version you can (stable, try all steps, if not helped - nightly)
2. Add [selected TF ops](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select) - this will expand amount of ops you can use. Apply and try convert:

   `converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [ tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, # enable TensorFlow Lite ops. tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS # enable TensorFlow ops. ]`
3. Allow [custom ops](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_custom) and investigate tflite model for them: `converter.allow_custom_ops = True`. While you still will unable to inference model you will find what ops should be changed.

Comment: As per the colab notebook, the tensorflow version is 1.X. This answer seems to suggest to use `Tensorflow2.0` correct me If I'm wrong

Comment: Latest that will work. Tensorflow2.0 convertor has backward compatibility with 1.x models, so I do not see potential issues

Comment: Tflite conversion is supported on tensorflow 2.4.0 nightly build & only on ssd-mobilenet. The question has/had been tagged as tensorflow2.0. That misled me. But that colab OP has referred us completely on tensorflow1.0. So not only this answer is confusing (answer should be for tflite1.0) as you have written an answer which might work for tensorflow2.0 and might not work in helping OP.